# Change navigation icon in sliding menu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu, android-sliding

i'm using Sliding menu by [jfeinstein10](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), here i have succesfully set the custom navigation icon for sliding menu.

i have done it in my style.xml like

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_navigation_drawer</item>

</style>
```

Now, if i open a new activity, there also i'm seeing the custom home indicator icon & i'm not getting the default back arrow in the new activity which i open from sliding menu.

For eg: in Gmail, by default if we slide a navigation icon will be present in all mail view. But if we go to compose new email the homeupindicator icon changes, how to do?

Comment: FYI gmail app uses navigation drawer not your jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu library....

Comment: Hmm, yes but i want to do using  jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu lib, any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

[A detailed explanation of changing the actionbar homeasupindicator](http://www.feelzdroid.com/2014/10/programmatically-change-android-action-bar-homeAsUpIndicator-navigation-icon.html)

[Change the actionbar homeAsUpIndicator Programamtically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585892/change-the-actionbar-homeasupindicator-programamtically)

This is what i did to acheive the behavior. I inherited the base theme and created a new theme to use it as a theme for the specific activity.

```
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/custom_home_as_up_icon</item>
</style>
```

and in the android manifest i made the activity theme as the above.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.CustomActivity"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActivityTheme" >
</activity>
```

works great. TRy like this for all activities it works like charm.

Comment: help plz . i DONE EXACTLY AS YOU SAID BUT Nothing happened

Comment: What is the result you are getting, have u included style in ur manifest file properly?, have u created style properly?

Comment: ya i have done it . there is a little space but no icon is showing.

Comment: Hello, can u see this post, it explains clearly, http://www.feelzdroid.com/2014/10/programmatically-change-android-action-bar-homeAsUpIndicator-navigation-icon.html. for sure u will understand, if you face any issues let me know