# Display Back Arrow on Toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I'm migrating from `ActionBar` to `Toolbar` in my application. 
But I don't know how to display and set click event on Back Arrow on `Toolbar` like I did on `Actionbar`.

[image]

With `ActionBar`, I call `mActionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`.
But there is no the similar method like this.

Has anyone ever faced this situation and somehow found a way to solve it?

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/a/29809691/1644301

Comment: Use getSupportActionBar() example here  http://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-add-back-arrow-in-android-activity/

Comment: Related post - [How to display and set click event on Back Arrow on Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35810229/465053)

Answer (score 1050, accepted):

If you are using an `ActionBarActivity` then you can tell Android to use the `Toolbar` as the `ActionBar` like so:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And then calls to

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

will work. You can also use that in Fragments that are attached to `ActionBarActivities` you can use it like this:

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

If you are not using `ActionBarActivities` or if you want to get the back arrow on a `Toolbar` that's not set as your `SupportActionBar` then you can use the following:

```
mActionBar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_back));
mActionBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       //What to do on back clicked
   }
});
```

If you are using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, then you should add the following code to your `AppCompatActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @MrEngineer13 Where did you get the ic_action_back drawable from?

Comment: Googles official Material Design icon repo https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/navigation/drawable-xhdpi/ic_arrow_back_black_48dp.png

Comment: If you're using the latest version of appcompat-v7 (21.0.3 or higher), you can use R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha for back arrow drawable, which is included in support library.

Comment: Please note that getResources().getDrawable(...) is deprecated. You should use ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, ...) instead.

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated (@deprecated Use {@link android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity} instead.). Does this mean one has to handle click events manually?

Comment: @hgoebl no, just use AppCompatActivity class instead of ActionBarActivity.

Comment: Didnt work, cannot find neither `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` neither `R.drawable.ic_action_back`.

Comment: What to do at `onClick(View v)`? Just call `onBackPressed()`

Comment: if I set setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) and setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); to enalbe back arrow. Then title is not coming center. I have tried like setting actionBar.setTitle(""); and setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false). But still not able to solve the issue

Comment: It is worth noting that those drawables might not be available in some versions of Android (for example, they are not available in certain versions of CyanogenMod). Therefore, the best practice is to COPY them to your project. Otherwise you will inevitably face a few crashes..

Comment: to get "back" icon from support library 
`toolbar.setNavigationIcon(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);`

Comment: Instead on manually implement onBackPressed(); you can use the proper back navigation provided by google https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Comment: `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material` this worked for me getting the back icon.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with overriding `onSupportNavigateUp()`, I cannot think of a reason that the back arrow and the back button should do different things.

Comment: it's better to use resource id method then drawable method... `mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_left);`

Comment: setSupportActionBar works. Thanks. In my case i also wanted to change the color so i did: toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: You're my savior! Banging my head since two days. This piece of code helped `onSupportNavigateUp()`

Comment: in my case we were overriding the toolbar and needed to set the navigation icon expliclty  thank you

Answer (score 253):

I see a lot of answers but here is mine which is not mentioned before. It works from API 8+.

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    // toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // add back arrow to toolbar
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: This only works if you set the Toolbar as the ActionBar. It is not for standalone toolbars.

Comment: Upvote for `onOptionItemSelected()` This completes what MrEngineer13 has not covered in his answer.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Seems to be better than using click listener, i do not really care about standalone toolbars

Comment: How can I change the color of the arrow?

Comment: I didn't need the lines under "toolbar" comment line, works nice.

Comment: The only answer that actually shows how navigate back by calling `finish()` and not just providing a useless comment like `// handle back button`.

Comment: Note that you don't need to create your own toolbar, if your theme already apply it

Answer (score 246):

There are many ways to achieve that, here is my favorite:

Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator" />
```

Activity:

```java
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // back button pressed
    }
});
```

Comment: using the theme attribute is much better than most of the other suggestions in this question

Comment: instead of using `setNavigationOnClickListener()` you can add `case android.R.id.home:` inside 'onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Comment: `case android.R.id.home` didn't worked for me. so after search for a while, your answer did the trick.. thanks.

Comment: This is the most authentic solution especially if you want to use default back icon of android system.

Comment: using toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener{ onBackPressed() }

Comment: dont have the default icon

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion, because it doesn't require you to modify the ActionBar state.

Comment: In the case of not setting it as the supportActionBar, this is the best answer for manipulating the toolbar.

Comment: crash, toolbar is a wrong type

Answer (score 75):

you can use the tool bar setNavigationIcon method.
[Android Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

```
mToolBar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);

mToolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        handleOnBackPress();
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.

Comment: Please note method `setNavigationOnClickListener()` has been added in api level 21 and above

Comment: R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha is now gone in support 23.2.0, use accepted answer instead.

Answer (score 39):

If you don't want to create a custom `Toolbar`, you can do like this

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...  
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Select Image");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In you `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".GalleryActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">        
</activity>
```

you can also put this `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to `<aplication>` tag, for apply to all activities

[image]

Comment: Thanks for `if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)`

Comment: Perfect Solution

Answer (score 24):

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_arrow); // your drawable
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed(); // Implemented by activity
        }
    });
```

And for API 21+ `android:navigationIcon`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:navigationIcon="@drawable/back_arrow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

Answer (score 21):

If your are using the `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` just use:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then just define in the `Manifest.xml` the parent Activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    ...>
  <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
      android:value=".ParentActivity" />
</activity>
```

Instead if you are using a `Toolbar` and you want a custom behavior just use:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar" 
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    .../>
```

and in your Activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //....
    }
});
```

Answer (score 20):

I used this method from the [Google Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

If you get a null pointer exception it could depend on the theme. Try using a different theme in the manifest or use this alternatively:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Then in the manifest, where I set the parent activity for current activity:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MyCurrentActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
     android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myapp.MyMainActivity" />
</activity>
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: The google docs link and the `getSupportActionBar()` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

If you **were** using `AppCompatActivity` and have gone down the path of not using it, because you wanted to not get the automatic `ActionBar` that it provides, because you want to separate out the `Toolbar`, because of your Material Design needs and `CoordinatorLayout` or `AppBarLayout`, then, consider this:

You can still use the `AppCompatActivity`, you don't need to stop using it just so that you can use a `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` in your xml. Just turn off the action bar **style** as follows:

First, derive a style from one of the NoActionBar themes that you like in your `styles.xml`, I used `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` like so:

```
<style name="SuperCoolAppBarActivity" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    ...
    ...
</style>
```

In your App's manifest, choose the child style theme you just defined, like so:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.YourSuperCoolActivity"
        android:label="@string/super_cool"
        android:theme="@style/SuperCoolAppBarActivity">
    </activity>
```

In your Activity Xml, if the toolbar is defined like so:

```
...
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />
...
```

Then, and this is the important part, you **set** the support Action bar to the AppCompatActivity that you're extending, so that the toolbar in your xml, *becomes* the action bar. I feel that this is a better way, because you can simply do the many things that ActionBar allows, like menus, automatic activity title, item selection handling, etc. without resorting to adding custom click handlers, etc.

In your Activity's onCreate override, do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_super_cool);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //Your toolbar is now an action bar and you can use it like you always do, for example:
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

### In Kotlin it would be

```
private fun setupToolbar(){
    toolbar.title = getString(R.string.YOUR_TITLE)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
}

// don't forget click listener for back button
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    onBackPressed()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(arrow -> onBackPressed());
    }
```

Comment: You can use retrolambda.

Comment: this is what i have and its not working. cant figure it out.

Answer (score 9):

Simple and easy way to show back button on toolbar

Paste  this code in onCreate method

```
 if (getSupportActionBar() != null){

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
```

Paste this override method  outside the onCreate method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()== android.R.id.home) {

        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Easily you can do it.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Credits:
https://freakycoder.com/android-notes-24-how-to-add-back-button-at-toolbar-941e6577418e

Answer (score 6):

First, you need to initialize the toolbar :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

then call the back button from the action bar :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In the `AppCompatActivity` for example you can do

```
public class GrandStatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grand_stat);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Display custom title
        ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.fragment_title_grandstats);

        // Display the back arrow
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    // Back arrow click event to go to the parent Activity
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your manifest file for the activity where you want to 
add a back button, we will use the property **android:parentActivityName**

```
        <activity
        android:name=".WebActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        />
```

[P.S.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#parent) This attribute was introduced in API Level 16.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the back arrow on a Toolbar that's not set as your SupportActionBar:

(kotlin)

```
val resId = getResIdFromAttribute(toolbar.context, android.R.attr.homeAsUpIndicator)
toolbarFilter.navigationIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(toolbar.context, resId)
toolbarFilter.setNavigationOnClickListener { fragmentManager?.popBackStack() }
```

to get res from attributes:

```
@AnyRes
fun getResIdFromAttribute(context: Context, @AttrRes attr: Int): Int {
    if (attr == 0) return 0
    val typedValueAttr = TypedValue()
    context.theme.resolveAttribute(attr, typedValueAttr, true)
    return typedValueAttr.resourceId
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**This worked perfectly**

```
public class BackButton extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_box);
        Toolbar chatbox_toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.chat_box_toolbar);
        chatbox_toolbar.setTitle("Demo Back Button");
        chatbox_toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        setSupportActionBar(chatbox_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        chatbox_toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Define Back Button Function
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow 3 steps if you want to handle your problem fastly & simply:

Add file ic_arrow.xml to Drawable folder with some codes below (add codes below into ic_arrow.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:tint="@color/black"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24"
tools:ignore="ExtraText">
<path
    android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
    android:pathData="M20,11H7.83l5.59,-5.59L12,4l-8,8 8,8 1.41,-1.41L7.83,13H20v-2z" />
</vector>
```

Add `ImageButton` to `Toolbar` (make sure the Toolbar customized, not Titlebar or Statusbar) - You can customize the ImageButton (arrow button) position if you want

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/arrow"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Add the `setArrowButton` method to `DetailActivity.java` (or any xxxActivity.java that you need)

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton arrowButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    arrowButton = findViewById(R.id.arrow);

    setArrowButton(arrowButton);
}

public void setArrowButton(ImageButton arrowButton) {
    arrowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish(); //will close the moment activity and return to 
                      //the last activity
        }
    });
   }
}
```

Done

Preview about arrowButton

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this to activity's xml in layout folder:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/prod_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Make toolbar clickable, add these to onCreate method:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.prod_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With Kotlin it became:

Xml:

```
<include
android:id="@+id/tbSignToolbar "
layout="@layout/toolbar_sign_up_in"/>
```

In your Activity:-

```
setSupportActionBar(tbSignToolbar as Toolbar?)//tbSignToolbar :id of your toolbar 
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a more reliable way to get the up icon from your theme (if not using the toolbar as your action bar):

```
toolbar.navigationIcon = context.getDrawableFromAttribute(R.attr.homeAsUpIndicator)
```

In order to turn the theme attribute into a drawable I used an extension function:

```
fun Context.getDrawableFromAttribute(attributeId: Int): Drawable {
    val typedValue = TypedValue().also { theme.resolveAttribute(attributeId, it, true) }
    return resources.getDrawable(typedValue.resourceId, theme)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **DrawerLayout** with **ActionBarDrawerToggle**, then to show **Back** button instead of **Menu** button (and viceversa), you need to add this code in your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.application_name, R.string.application_name);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_32dp);
    mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed(); // Or you can perform some other action here when Back button is clicked.
        }
    });
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    // ...
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        return true;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        // ...
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void showBackInToolbar(boolean isBack) {
    // Remove next line if you still want to be able to swipe to show drawer menu.
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(isBack ? DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED : DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(!isBack);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

So when you need to show **Back** button instead of **Menu** button, call **showBackInToolbar(true)**, and if you need **Menu** button, call **showBackInToolbar(false)**.

You can generate back arrow (ic_arrow_back_white_32dp) [over here](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=arrow_back&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=32&padding=8&color=rgb(255%2C%20255%2C%20255)&name=ic_arrow_back), search *arrow_back* in **Clipart** section (use default 32dp with 8dp padding). Just select the color you want.

Answer (score 0):

**You can always add a `Relative layout` or a `Linear Layout` in your `Toolbar` and place a Image view for back icon or close icon anywhere in toolbar as you like**

For example I have used Relative layout in my toolbar

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:nextFocusDown="@id/netflixVideoGridView"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Myflix"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textSize="19sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/red"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/closeMyFlix"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_close" />


                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

You can add click listener on that image view from Activity or fragment like this.

```
  closeMyFlix.setOnClickListener({
            Navigator.instance.showFireTV(  activity!!.supportFragmentManager)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JetPack Navigation.

Here is the layout for MainActivity

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                               xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                               android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                               tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
```

SetUp your toolbar in your activity like below in onCreate() of your Activity class.

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment? ?: return

val navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()
val toolBar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolBar)
setSupportActionBar(toolBar) // To set toolBar as ActionBar
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
```

setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)  Will create a back button on the toolBar if needed and handles the backButton functionality.
If you need to write a CustomBack functionality, create a callBack as below on your fragment onCreate() method

```
val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
        // Handle the back button event
    }
```

From Documentation:https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help someone,I didn't find in the answares the thing I did by the end:
with ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
to show the back arrow in toolbar set:
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

and if you want it to show the hamburger in the toolbar:

mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

Vasil Valchev codes work fine for me. But if parent activity has set action bar to toolbar by `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`, there is no need to set it again.

One more thing: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)` can be omitted as setting true of false has no effect.

This is the modification:

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);    

    // add back arrow to toolbar, no null check too
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```