# Android: How to disable the ActionBar button that opens navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to disable the ActionBar button that opens navigation drawer?

I use the code below to disable opening the navigation drawer using swipe, but its action bar button (at Top/Left) still active and can be used to open the navigation drawer.

```
 DrawerLayout navigationDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 navigationDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Comment: try returning false in `onOptionsItemSelected` for `android.R.id.home` button.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54992406/1223728).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This i think it Will help you

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

or you can use this

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked well, it hides the button in the action bar, but what if I want to override this button rather than hiding it, I mean, to change its icon (To be as back button) and rather than opening the drawer I use it to be as back button, is it possible?

Comment: Thanks, by any chance do you have any article talking about this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use setNavigationOnClickListener() on toolbar to avoid Nav Drawer from opening.

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
         // your code.
     }
});
```

Nav drawer will open just by swiping, and not by clicking on the menu item button.