# Android Back Arrow on Toolbar (AppCompatActivity)

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar, android-actionbar-compat, appcompatactivity

I want to show the back arrow button in my app, but the app crashes when I put this in my code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

**style.xml**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ControlHighlight</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>


<style name="ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>


<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
</style>


<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
android:elevation="0dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"/>
```

**Class (not Fragment)**:

```
public class WebViewCanale extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView textView;
    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_canali);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        //Toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        //FindViewById
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        //Impostazioni WebView
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.loadUrl(this.getIntent().getDataString());
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);

        //Titolo Toolbar
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
                    WebViewCanale.this.setTitle(title);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: place this code `toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` before this code `setSupportActionBar(toolbar); getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

Comment: not work... same crash

Comment: @SimoneVarletta 'some crash' is not a helpful description.

Comment: @KaranMer Sorry man!! perfectly WORK!!

Answer (score 33):

You can also just declare in the `Manifest` a `ParentActivity` with:

`<activity 
    android:name=".ThisActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".TheActivityThatCalledThisOne">
 </activity>`

Comment: this is correct , you don't need to add your own Actionbar to the XML file, instead, just add this simple code android:parentActivityName=".TheParentActivityNameHere". to the Manifest and use any theme in the styles that have an Action bar. and for the Activity (to add your own menu) just override the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

Answer (score 28):

I wonder why there's not a complete answer for this on SO, but finally I solved the matter on my own:

Use the following snippet to have **back button** on the **toolbar** in an **AppCompatActivity**:

```
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.hack_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //do something you want
            }
        });
```

Comment: Complete answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26656285/1911652) but yours having precise code for `Toolbar`

Answer (score 8):

### Update

```kotlin
      private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<DetailActivityBinding>(
          activity,
          R.layout.detail_activity
        )
        toolbar = binding.toolbar
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        activity.supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        activity.supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
      }
```

### Original

```
 @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
 Toolbar toolbar;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_events);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
 }
```

`onSupportNavigateUp()`
This method is called whenever the user chooses to navigate Up within your application's activity hierarchy from the action bar.

`onBackPressed();`
Take care of popping the fragment back stack or finishing the activity as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

add this theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/appColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/whiteColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/appColor</item>
</style>
```

and in you activity:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set support actionbar first before your can get it. so place the following code

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); 
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**Before this Code**

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```