# android - Implement UP button action with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, up-button

## Question

I am using Navigation Drawer from Android Studio Template. I want to use **UP button (arrow)** in some of my fragments instend **"Hamburger" button**.
I use `AppCompatActivity`.

I use this code to show UP button arrow:

```
public void UseUpButton(boolean value) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (value) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    } else {
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

## Tried variants:

But I can't catch click on this button. I tried some ways:

#### Use `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Log.d("WTF", "menu");
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I add `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` to my `Activity::onCreate`, but `onOptionsItemSelected` not called when I press the Up button and works correctly when I press the menu items.

#### Use ActionBarToggle OnClickListener

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,       
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
 });
```

But this method doesn't call at Up button press too.

## Conclusion:

So, how can I catch the Up button press event?

Comment: where you want Up Button on activity or fragment??

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54992406/1223728)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this somewhere few days ago...

In my code I initialize `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. It has some constructors, but I interested in this:

#### 1

```
public ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout,
        @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes,
        @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {
    this(activity, null, drawerLayout, null, openDrawerContentDescRes,
            closeDrawerContentDescRes);
}
```

#### 2

```
public ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout,
        Toolbar toolbar, @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes,
        @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {
    this(activity, toolbar, drawerLayout, null, openDrawerContentDescRes,
            closeDrawerContentDescRes);
}
```

Take a look: 2nd constructor **has `Toolbar toolbar` argument**.

If you want to handle `UP BUTTON` events **DO NOT USE 2nd CONSTUCTOR** and use first.

Example:

```
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawer,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

`setHomeButtonEnabled` is important, without this you won't see Hamburger or Up button.

Comment: `setHomeButtonEnabled` didnt work for me. But `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` works, also if you want to show the arrow, remember to set `isDrawerIndicatorEnabled` to false

Answer (score 3):

I added a few lines to your method so it would implement the back button:

```
  public void useUpButton(boolean value) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (value) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    } else {
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: To show the arrow navigation instead of the drawer hamburguer you just need switch `isDrawerIndicatorEnabled` to false

Answer (score 1):

For the default behavior which makes the hamburger button open drawer you can just use this code

```
    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

then to override the default behaviour in any of the child activity, do this

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  // shows the up navigation button instead of the hamburger

    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            finish(); //end current activity
        }
    });
```

When ActionBarDrawerToggle takes toolbar as input, it sets its own NavigationOnClickListener on toolbar. we can override this to call our code when up button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you want to intercept the action bar items click from a fragment you need at first add this to your fragment onCreate:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Than just use the right method onOptionsItemSelected (fragment version different when you use in an activity):

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.your_action:
                //do something
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }//onOptionsItemSelected
```

Comment: This doesn't work - ```onOptionsItemSelected``` doesn't call  when I press UP button

Answer (score 0):

Hope It will Help You...

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);//for fragment
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        //do samething
    }
}
```

or use this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);//for fragment
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is exists in Navigation Drawer template. I implement here pop fragments from stack, but it only work on hardware back button, not up button in application bar