# Change Home Button back to left arrow for one activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-homebutton

I have set the `homeAsUpIndicator` to

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_menu_icon</item>
```

globally in a stylesheet. Every Activity has the same icon now.

How can I change the icon in the ActionBar to be the left arrow (<-) again for one activity despite having it set globally in the stylesheet?

I tried to access `android.R.drawable.ic_menu_back` but I cannot access it (it seems it is private):

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false); // does not work
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // does not work
// does not compile: getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_back);
```

Comment: use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: The name of the left arrow icon included with appcompat-v7 is `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` not `ic_menu_back`. As in `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` without the `android:` prefix.

Comment: That's perfect Eugen. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It was probably updated some time ago, because I've found it under `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Back Arrow on Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651602/display-back-arrow-on-toolbar)

Answer (score 2):

You can download this icon from the design google web page [here](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#getting-icons) it name is `ic_arrow_back_white` drop it into your drawable folder and then you would be able to acces it.

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_back_24dp);
```

Comment: I am already using the appcompat-v7 library so Eugen's solution works best for me. Thanks though

Comment: Well yes nice to hear