# Android app - Back button

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to display a back button in the left corner of the action bar and I do not completely know where to make the change in the *activity.java* to make it visible and functional.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstancesState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

This is what I want to display.
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMY2M.png)

Comment: `actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled`, though you should be using the toolbar instead of the old actionbar

Comment: I'm getting an error in the code. It's written in red text. I think your code is wrong and I maybe wrong about that but do you have a different solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: oops sorry its `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`

Comment: It's showing an error and suggested to rename the reference.

Comment: well you reference is `actionBar` hopefully you didnt just copy and past exactly what I wrote

Comment: Try this way -`actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: Well, I did not just copy and paste your code. Although I implemented it in the activity and it displayed an error. I really appreciate you taking the time to solve my post.

Comment: `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` this is in red

Comment: please post what the error says

Comment: tyczj you somewhat solved my question but @ShadabAnsari fully solved it

Comment: The problem is that it's not functional. It doesn't go back to the previous activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Back Arrow on Toolbar Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651602/display-back-arrow-on-toolbar-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to enable it by doing

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

then if you want it to do something you need to look for the click in the `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            //do something here
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Showing it is as simple as putting this under your onCreate method in your Activity:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then to control that input put this in your Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            //or do what you want
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// activity

```
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

// fragments

```
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

It may helps some one