# Toolbar title is transparent

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have an AppCompatActivity with transparent Toolbar. The problem is that on devices below API 21 the title and the arrow (up navigation) of the toolbar is transparent. I know it is there because clicking the invisable arrow brings me back to the last activity. Devices with API 21 and above show a white title and white back arrow.

My styles.xml ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29907616))

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!-- from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar -->
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and my styles.xml(v21)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>

<!-- from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar -->
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

The toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I also tried adding `app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"` and wrapping the toolbar in an `AppBarLayout`. Without any success.

-----EDIT------
The important part of the AppCompatActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
...

public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_view);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        String title = ...
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In You `Activity.java` import `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` instead of `android.widget.Toolbar`

In your **Activity.java** in **`onCreate()`**

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //getting the support actionbar for api lower then 21
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_view);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

you can also look into this [android transparent action bar and status bar showing arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651602/display-back-arrow-on-toolbar-android?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly it didn't help. I've already imported the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. I have added the important part of the code of the Avtivity the my main post.

Comment: in your App theme in style.xml, add:

          `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`

Comment: No change. Probably because my style is already derived from `*.NoActionBar`.