# Adding UP navigation setDisplayShowHomeEnabled null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-actionbar, uinavigationbar

I'm getting (AS) warnings and a null pointer when trying to enable the "UP Navigation" on an activity.

`: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference`

I've tried two different methods ([Display Back Arrow on Toolbar Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651602/display-back-arrow-on-toolbar-android)) but without success.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ViewMyHistory extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_requests);

        Toolbar appToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(appToolbar);

        //This gives errors
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 

        //and so does this
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is okay. The only possible problem is that you may not have a `Toolbar` with id `R.id.mainToolbar` inside your layout file `R.layout.my_requests`.

If you don't want to use a `Toolbar`, use an appcompat theme with an action bar as the parent theme of your `AppTheme`(or whatever your activity is using) in `styles.xml` such as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: The toolbar is there... `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mainToolbar" ....`

Comment: @Maxcot And is it in `my_requests.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either one of this :

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
// OR 
 getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```