# Creating a back button with noActionBar

Tags: java, android, back-button

I'm a couple days into learning Android development and I'll admit my code is not pretty, as I have a few weeks of Java under my belt on top of this.  I'm trying to create a back button on my 2nd main activity page to get back to the 1st main activity, but the only solutions I've come across are while using the toolbar.  How would you go about adding this function while using noActionBar?

Main Activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/clearwater"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
tools:context="com.example.goodvibes.helloworld.MainActivity">



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="146dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:text="DIVE"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity 2 xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
tools:context="com.example.goodvibes.helloworld.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:background="@drawable/timebutton"
    android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
    android:text="Time Interval Between Dives"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:tint="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:srcCompat="?android:attr/actionModeCloseDrawable" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity Java

```
package com.example.goodvibes.helloworld;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button but1;

    public void init(){
        but1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent toy = new 
 Intent(MainActivity.this,activity_main_2.class);

                startActivity(toy);

            }
        });
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();{
}
}

}
```

Main Activity 2 Java

```
package com.example.goodvibes.helloworld;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ViewAnimator;

public class activity_main_2 extends AppCompatActivity {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);




}
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.goodvibes.helloworld">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity_main_2"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I had a lot of great people giving me answers I had to research.  In the end here is what solved my problem: I inserted "android:onClick="ImageButton" under my button code in the xml fine THEN under the corresponding java file for my second activity I inserted:

```
public void ImageButton(View v)
{
    // some code
    finish();
}
```

Comment: call finish(); method on that button click. simple :)

Comment: do as Rohit Singh suggested use can use imageview and on imageview click you can call finish();

Comment: Possible duplicate of :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651602/display-back-arrow-on-toolbar-android

Comment: Step 1. Add a toolbar to your layout. And set a supportaction bar in your activity. Step 2. and then enable back button by calling `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` Step 3. Since back button is nothing but home button, handle its click event in `onOptionsItemSelected()`

Comment: Are you opposed to overriding `onBackPressed()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_acashmemoreport"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow" />
```

In your activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_acashmemoreport);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
}

// Show menu icon
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all you have to add a required toolbar and after making the toolbar you put the button inside the toolbar like following;

Update your xml layout file as,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_back_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Also include the below java code inside your Activity Class,

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ImageButton back=findViewById(R.id.btn_back_toolbar);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this,AnotherActivity.class));
        }
    });
```