# How to add a back navigation icon to an appBarLayout in java

Tags: java, android

Add back navigation to an appBarLayout, I want to add a toolbar inside an appBarLayout in xml, and then add a back arrow to that toolbar.

I have followed this and tried to adjust it for my needs, with no luck.
[Display Back Arrow on Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651602/display-back-arrow-on-toolbar)

Comment: link you have added, works perfectly. What's your exact issue ?

Comment: Please elaborate what you have tried and what issue you faced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout)

> AppBarLayout is a vertical LinearLayout

So you will need to include your toolbar and other components inside it, something like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent">

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Then you can add your back navigation button to the toolbar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Your_Toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And then calls to:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Override method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity do the following in `onCreate`

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();

if(bar != null){
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```